# What is the negation of the following statements?

Tags: geometry, logic

I need some help double checking my work and the teacher likes to obfuscate his answers.

I am negating the given statements regardless of whether they are true or false.

1:  Given a line and a point not on the line, there exists a line parallel to the given line through the given point.

My Answer:
 There exist some line A and some point Q not on A, such that there does not exist a line parallel to A through Q.

2:Given a line and a point not on the line, there exists a unique line parallel to the given line through the given point.

My Answer:
There exist some line A and some point Q not on the line A, such that there does not exist a unique line parallel to line A through point Q.

Comment: I think for #2, it should say "There exist a line A and a point Q not on line A such that there are two different lines B and C such that they both pass through Q and are parallel to A". #1 looks right though.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for the critique. If you post as an answer i can select it for you.

Comment: @2012ssohn But you also have to take into account the possibility that there are no parallel lines.

Comment: IF both are the case then can both be correct. That there could be both no parallel line or more than one distinct parallel line.  I'm not sure which part of the statement is actually being negated.

Comment: Your #2 statement is correct. I think what you said in your comment is right as well. But here are some comments to clarify. "...exists a unique..." has two things in it: there exists... __and__ ...is unique. So the negation "...there does not exist a unique..." can be broken into "...there does not exist... __or__ there exists more than one...". But breaking it down is not necessary.

Comment: Why make it this complicated?  In formal logic, we're  content to say that the negation of $\phi$ is $\lnot\phi$.  Why not just negate №1 as "_It is not the case that_ Given a line and a point not on the line there exists a line parallel to the given line through the given point." ?  You're doing more work by pushing the negation inward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negation of first statement made by you is correct and for statement 2 the negation can be like following:
1.   There exist some line A and some point Q not on the line A, such that there does not exist any line parallel to line A through point Q.

2.There exist some line A and some point Q not on the line A, such that there does exist more than one line parallel to line A through point Q.

Here both the above statements can be used as negation of the $2^{nd}$ statement provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

Statement 1) is :

$\forall a \forall q [q \notin a \rightarrow \exists l (paral(l,a) \land q \in l) ]$

Negating it we get :

$\exists a \exists q [q \notin a \land \lnot \exists l (paral(l,a) \land q \in l)]$,

or alternatively :

$\exists a \exists q [q \notin a \land \forall l (q \in l \rightarrow \lnot paral(l,a) )]$.

So, the translation of 1) is fine.

Statement 2) is :

$\forall a \forall q [q \notin a \rightarrow \exists! l (paral(l,a) \land q \in l) ]$

In this case, in order to get the desired result, It is necessary to "unwind" the *uniqueness* condition, getting:

$\forall a \forall q [q \notin a \rightarrow ( \exists l (paral(l,a) \land q \in l) \land \forall x ((paral(x,a) \land q \in x) \rightarrow x = l) ) ]$

Now, negating it, you will have : "there exists a line $a$ and a point $Q$ not on $a$ such that --- " and the negation of the *conjunction*.

This in turn will be the *disjunction* of the negations of the two sub-formulae; so, as suggested in his comment by *Pratyush Sarkar*, it will sound like :

"**or** all lines trough Q are *not* parallel to $a$, **or** there exists a line $x$ trough $Q$, *distinct* from $l$, that is parallel to $a$".